# Dealing with keyboard layout for input on Qt WebAssembly

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly

I am writing the Super Mario clone game for learning a programming, OpenGL ES, Box2D, OpenAL and so on (not for commerce). A keyboard works well when the system keyboard layout is set to English. But if the system keyboard layout is set to another language Mario cannot move and jump.

I solved this problem for Windows only by setting the system keyboard layout to English using WinAPI but how to solve it for WebAssembly?

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 1, 0x04090409);
#endif
```

Download my example to reproduce the problem: [keyboard-layout-qt6.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x3ispgte2wtzjkurawstr/keyboard-layout-qt6.zip?rlkey=ujnskxby6dgn7925eb3hs4yjz&dl=1). If your system keyboard layout is English you can press WAS or arrow-keys and see "left", "right", "jump" in the debug console. But if you change the system keyboard layout to another language you do not see the debug output.

keyboard-layout-qt6.pro

```
QT += core opengl gui widgets

win32: LIBS += -lopengl32

CONFIG += c++17

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

main.pp

```cpp
#include <QtGui/QKeyEvent>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

class OpenGLWindow : public QOpenGLWindow, private QOpenGLFunctions
{
    void initializeGL() override
    {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    }

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override
    {
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key::Key_W || event->key() == Qt::Key::Key_Up)
        {
            qDebug() << "jump";
        }
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key::Key_A || event->key() == Qt::Key::Key_Left)
        {
            qDebug() << "left";
        }
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key::Key_D || event->key() == Qt::Key::Key_Right)
        {
            qDebug() << "right";
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::ApplicationAttribute::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    OpenGLWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

- You can play in my demo in the browser: https://65faec4d823b731715d4ac45--vermillion-gnome-1f3770.netlify.app/ (Use WAD-keys or arrow-keys to control a character)
- Or download EXE for Windows 10 64-bit: [mario-2d-jump-with-rays-opengles2-qt6-cpp-win10x64-exe.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ep790wy6thog6xvcot7kv/mario-2d-jump-with-rays-opengles2-qt6-cpp-win10x64-exe.zip?rlkey=ltxo91qq7jaf677bfr1kpq622&dl=1)
- APK file for Android 7-14: [mario-2d-jump-with-rays-opengles2-qt6-cpp-android-7-14-apk.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/b10rr7od54vg7da6ti32n/mario-2d-jump-with-rays-opengles2-qt6-cpp-android-7-14-apk.zip?rlkey=23zeyj0gj0xn0ftxzrn8jhqx1&dl=1)

I made a level using [Free Texture Packer](http://free-tex-packer.com/) and [Tiled Map Editor](https://www.mapeditor.org/).

Desktop:

[image]

Android:

[image]

**Added 3/25/2024**

All resources (sprites, music and sounds) have been replaced with free ones. You can see a list of free resources [here](https://8observer8.github.io/webgl10-js/super-mario/). For example, I took the sprites here: https://webfussel.itch.io/more-bit-8-bit-mario

- [itch.io page](https://8observer8.itch.io/super-mario-clone-with-free-resources)
- [Click this link to play in the browser](https://66007db3fb849b1c9dc1258a--resonant-queijadas-c99ba6.netlify.app/) (use WAD or arrow keys to move and jump)
- [Download EXE for Windows 10, 64-bit](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/etse0yyv7utvwxwqt5ghy/mario-2d-jumps-webfussel-opengles2-qt6-cpp-win10x64-exe.zip?rlkey=4isi7m7gvjwh96wyc0day62zi&dl=1)
- [APK-file for Android](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4nhwh5pl29l56rx6am9b5/mario-2d-jumps-webfussel-opengles2-qt6-cpp-apk.zip?rlkey=sl6u60ecitraq235qg6jui47a&dl=1)

[image]

Comment: We don't know anything about how you're dealing with keypresses, providing the link to the program certainly doesn't help understand the problem, so you should at least provide the code relative to the issue.

Comment: @musicamante Done. Yes, I agree with you. Thank you

Comment: Qt internally maps received keycodes to the Qt.Key enums. You should probably look for the event's [`nativeVirtualKey()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#nativeVirtualKey) and compare it with a predefined map of keys in the WASD positions along with the common keyboard layouts depending on the system locale. But that could be quite difficult to create and maintain. It may be easier to add a basic configuration option that allows to select the layout or manually input alternate WASD keys. I don't know about webassembly, but maybe it's possible to filter key events *before* they reach »

Comment: » the webassembly content: if it is, you may be able to synthesize a keyboard event by checking the keyboard event [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) property and eventually send an arbitrary keyboard event that *actually* sends the intended WASD character.